# Do method needs to make synchronize if more than one thread created from a class extended thread class?

Tags: java

Following is my code

```
class ExtendsThread extends Thread {

   private int counter = 0;
   /* should I need to make Display synchronize ?*/
   public void Display() {
       counter++;
     System.out.println("ExtendsThread : Counter : " + counter);
   } 
   public void run() {
     Display();
   }
 }

public class MyMain{

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

//Creating new instance for every thread access.
     ExtendsThread tc1 = new ExtendsThread();
     tc1.start();
     Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
     ExtendsThread tc2 = new ExtendsThread();
     tc2.start();
     Thread.sleep(1000); // Waiting for 1 second before starting next thread
     ExtendsThread tc3 = new ExtendsThread();
     tc3.start();
}

output is :

ExtendsThread : Counter : 1
ExtendsThread : Counter : 1
ExtendsThread : Counter : 1
```

I read that When you extends Thread class, each of your thread creates unique object and associate with it hence counter is always one.

Now my question is do I need to synchronize Display method?
AS counter is always 1 because it is separate object, so we need not to use synchronize.
is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could synchronize access to a static counter, or you can use an `AtomicInteger`, which will handle the threadsafety for you...

```
class ExtendsThread extends Thread {
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public void Display() {
       System.out.println("ExtendsThread : Counter : " + counter.incrementAndGet());
    } 
    public void run() {
        Display();
    }
 }
```

The way you have it now, there is one instance of `counter` for each instance of `ExtendsThread`. If you want `counter` (or any field) to be shared among all of the instances of a specific class, you have to make them `static`. Since you'll have multiple threads accessing the now static counter, you'll have to control access to them so they don't cause a race condition. This is where `AtomicInteger` comes in - it handles all of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, each thread has its own copy of the `counter` variable, so there's no synchronization required. If the variable was shared between threads, then there should be synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronize` is used to prevent two threads to execute the method at the same time. You need to use synchronize but the key factor here is that you also need to make the variable `static`, so all the instances of the class share the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the only way to get different values is making the variable static like this:

```
private static int counter = 0;
```

If you do not want problems of holds with the threads is recommendable sinchronize the method.